# Gradle dependencies are downloaded everytime while creating docker image

Tags: docker, gradle, build.gradle

## build image

FROM java:8 as builder

RUN mkdir -p /binaries

ADD . /app-code/core-service

WORKDIR /app-code/core-service

RUN rm -rf .project .classpath .settings
RUN rm -rf  .gradle

RUN ./gradlew -Dgradle.user.home=/root/.gradle -Prelease.version=1.0-final clean

....

This starts downloading the dependencies again while creating the image second time.
Why does it not take the dependencies from root/.gradle folder ?

Comment: Why it should? Dependency cache will be stored in the _build container's_ file system. When you build the image second time, `gradle` runs in the file system, where cache just does not exist - it is left alone in the file system of _old_ build container.

Comment: @DanilaKiver It takes a lot of time for each image creation. Can't I mount my local machine's gradle home in container so that it could refer to this folder directly instead of going download the dependencies each time ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but looks like you cannot mount volumes during the image build: https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-mount-volume-created-during-build/28371.